# Summing numbers and then increasing used numbers

Tags: mathematics, game

I was making a mathematical game (viewable here: [www.michaelprimo.it/beta](http://www.michaelprimo.it/beta)) where you have a 3x3 grid, one central yellow button with a generated number and the other eight blue buttons with clickable and summable numbers. I thought: "what if everything is predictable?" So I made this:

- There are eight numbers: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, and a main number of value 2
- You must sum the numbers you have to reach exactly that number
- After that, all the numbers used for the sum AND the main number will be increased by 1

  - The next move will have 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, and 3 as a main number. Now we must select numbers to make a sum of 3.
- This is repeated until you finish the moves

**What is the biggest main number you can reach?** More importantly, is the game doable (as in no particular tricks and it's not broken in some way)

I want to know if this puzzle I accidentally created during my game is good or not. I am not good with game theory, but I am interested in the argument.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! What exactly do you mean by "doable"? What kinds of tricks are you worried about? How would it be "broken"?

Comment: Thank you! Well, maybe the game can be infinite by repeating a pattern and this shouldn't be happened. I tried and I am trying myself to solve it too and I don't think this will happen, but I decided to ask help to people more smarter than me for this task because I don't think to can do it now.

Comment: So you're asking what the highest possible main number is, **or** if a strategy/proof exists that would guarantee no highest possible number exists?

Comment: Actually both, but I am more interested of the first question. If the second question is true then the main number can be infinite, but if there is a proof the puzzle is not broken by some pattern then the main number can reach a finite limit and we need to know what is that limit.

Comment: If the starting (playable) squares contained (2,1,1,1) instead of (1,1,1,...) then it is easy to reach any number.

Comment: Yes, because you can simply use the highest number without any combinations. I thought even something like: 4,5,5,5 (and other numbers) with the main number 9 and you can simply do 4,5 and then 5,5 , 5,6 , 6,6 ,6,7 , 7,7 and so on, but it seems this can't be happening and I am glad for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest number you can reach is

> 38

This is because

> I ran an exhaustive brute force search to play all possible games. (*Disclaimer: this python code is just a quick hack, there are better ways to implement this.*)
>
> ```
> from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_partitions
>
> for K in range(1,9):
>     G = [[2]+[1 for i in range(K)]]
>     m = 2
>     game_states = set()
>     while True:
>       game = G.pop(-1)
>       if tuple(game) not in game_states:
>           game_states.add(tuple(game))
>           if sum(game[1:])==game[0]:
>               G.append([i+1 for i in game])
>               if G[-1][0]>m:
>                   m=G[-1][0]
>           else:
>               for msp in multiset_partitions(game[1:],2):
>                   if sum(msp[0])==game[0]:
>                       G.append(sorted([game[0]+1]+[i+1 for i in msp[0]]+msp[1],reverse=True))
>                   elif sum(msp[1])==game[0]:
>                       G.append(sorted([game[0]+1]+[i+1 for i in msp[1]]+msp[0],reverse=True))
>                   if len(G)>0 and G[-1][0]>m:
>                       m=G[-1][0]
>       if len(G)==0:
>           break
>   print(K,m)
> ```

As a bonus, highest reachable numbers a(k) on k=1,2,...,8 tiles are:

> ```
> k a(k)
> 1 2
> 2 3
> 3 5
> 4 5
> 5 8
> 6 11
> 7 17
> 8 38
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I done 38 before, so I guess I reached without knowing the limit of the puzzle without knowing it. At least we know now it's not flawed and have a solution. Thank you again!

Comment: @MichaelPrimo The general problem could be interesting. On 9 tiles, the biggest reachable number is 468 (or more). It appears this sequence grows very quickly.

Comment: That is interesting, I don't know why since I can't describe what kind of puzzle/problem is this. Maybe I can think about it when I will put it to the game I am making (in fact the puzzle is an alternative to the game I made here: www.michaelprimo.it , without the beta. ) The yellow number is generated random this time and you have a time limit in fact the puzzle was born as a "what if" and then I liked it, I was curious about finding more and here I am.